# Neo4j.Driver.V1.ClientException deadlock

Tags: c#, neo4j, deadlock

Anyone have any idea how to solve deadlock in neo4j. The detail of the exception

> Neo4j.Driver.V1.ClientException: 'Error when pulling unconsumed
>   session.run records into memory in session: ForsetiClient[2] can't
>   acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[4]} on NODE(1122), because
>   holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[2].  Wait
>   list:ExclusiveLock[ Client[4] waits for [2]]'

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: info: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-deadlockdetectedexception-forseticlient-0-cant-acquire-exclusivelock/

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the [deadlock article](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-deadlockdetectedexception-forseticlient-0-cant-acquire-exclusivelock/) mentioned by @JohnB, there is [documentation on deadlocks and how to handle them](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transactions/#transactions-deadlocks).

Frequently, a deadlock is the result of a race condition between different transactions, so your code can just retry the transactions that received the `DeadlockDetectedException`. See the documentation linked above for an example of a retry loop. *You should also consider having each transaction randomizing the retry intervals a bit, to minimize the possibility that multiple transactions will retry at about the same time.*